# Error build release layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

When I press on build release I get the problem but when I press on debug there is no problem:

> Error:(52) Error: The id "recycler_viewContainer" is not defined anywhere. [UnknownId]
>
> Error:(52) Error: @id/recycler_view is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout [NotSibling]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    tools:context="ru.ifsoft.mymarketplace.StreamFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container_body" >

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_items"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorRipple" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change @+id/profileListView instead of @id/profileListView

Comment: Why don't use `profileContainer` instead ? `app:layout_anchor="@+id/profileContainer"`

Comment: I did not understand what should I do @Nizam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your xml siblings structure and the error.

[image: Direct siblings with error]

The error is, `profileListView` is not a direct sibling. ie, it is inside the direct sibling, LinearLayout `profileContainer`

[image: Direct sibling id]

So we will give the direct sibling id to fix the problem.

[image: Direct sibling id given]

Likewise, give an id to the parent of `recycler_view`, and use it to sove the direct sibling problem for `recycler_view`.

```
 <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/container_body" // Used id of the LinerLayout, which is the direct sibling of the root layout
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorRipple" />
```

Comment: Edited by now you please help me

Comment: RecylerView is in another layout. right? Use `app:layout_anchor="@+id/container_body"` for that FloatingActionButton

Comment: I do not understand Likewise, give an id to the parent of recycler_view, and use it to sove the direct sibling problem for recycler_view.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand you need to explain more, such as the following problem you solve them for the good Bhrg

Comment: where are you ?

Comment: Edited the answer. Now, do you understand what direct sibling is?

Answer (score 0):

Change in FloatingActionButton

`app:layout_anchor="@id/profileListView"` to

`app:layout_anchor="@+id/profileContainer"`

app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"  to

app:layout_anchor="@+id/container_body"

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its work Keep me one problem like them can you help me?
Error:(52) Error: @id/recycler_view is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout [NotSibling]

Comment: Check or post here xml file in which you are using recycle_view.

Comment: Edited by now you please help me